# Why does it say "arrive to" , not "arrive at"?

Tags: prepositions

I have found the sentences below in the UK newspaper *The Guardian*.
Why does it say "arrive to", not "arrive at" ?

> Prosecutors from the House of Representatives, known as “managers”,
>   are expected to arrive to the Senate at midday local time (5pm GMT) to
>   formally exhibit the articles of impeachment against Donald Trump,
>   approved last month by the House.
>
> — [*Senate gets ready to open impeachment trial against Donald Trump*](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/jan/16/us-senate-impeachment-trial-donald-trump)

Answer (score 0):

The written rules in both British and American English say 'arrive *to* (some place)' is always a mistake.

https://www.dailywritingtips.com/about/

However, it happens from time to time, even in books ('arrive to school on time' is used often enough). This time, The Guardian's site used the material from its Washington correspondents. US papers wrote '*(expected to) arrive **at** the Senate*' and *'arrive **in** the Senate*' in their articles on the same subject. In another context the preposition **on** is possible (island or shore).

Comment: I think you can say "arrive to a conclusion"? At least I heard it said before.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Alex.                                        I understand "to" is wrong. I had trusted newspapers, but being newspapers don't always mean they are correct, do they? I wonder which newpaper is the most reliable.

Comment: I can remember the recommended version from a training software: _arrive **at** a conclusion_. So says this dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/arrive

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/arrive-at-vs-arrive-to-usage) suggests "arrives to" is becoming increasingly common; it was used as early as the 16th century, but fell out of favour in the 18th.

Comment: One hears of pedantically-minded UK rail passengers being annoyed if the train staff announce over the loudspeakers e.g. that 'this train will soon be arriving **into** Swindon'. It seems to be a fairly recent thing.